# NumPy: Check if field exists

Tags: numpy

I have a structured `numpy` array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros(1, dtype = [('field0', 'i2'), ('field1', 'f4')])
```

Then I start to retrieve some values. However, I do not know in advance, if my array contains a certain field. Therefore, if I try to reach a non-existing field, I am expectedly getting `IndexError`:

```
>>> a[0]['field0']
0
>>> a[0]['field2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
```

I could of course go with `try-except`; however, this can potentially mask some errors, as `IndexError` does not specify, on which level I hit the non-existing index:

```
>>> try:
...     a[9999]['field2']['subfield3']
... except IndexError:
...     print('Some index does not exist')
... 
Some index does not exist
```

I also tried to approach `numpy` arrays as lists, but this does not work:

```
>>> if 'field0' in a[0]:
...     print('yes')
... else:
...     print('no')
... 
no
```

**Therefore, question:** Is there a way to check if a given field exists in a structured `numpy` array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check `.dtype.names` or `.dtype.fields`:

```
>>> a.dtype.names
('field0', 'field1')
>>> 'field0' in a.dtype.names
True
>>> a.dtype.fields
mappingproxy({'field0': (dtype('int16'), 0), 'field1': (dtype('float32'), 2)})
>>> 'field0' in a.dtype.fields
True
```